# Macbook Pro shuts down at around 50% battery

Tags: macos, battery, macbook-pro

I have a mid 2012 13" Macbook Pro. I had changed the battery with an  after market battery and it works, however, it doesn't last as long as the original one.

Recently I did an SMC reset due to another problem, and now my battery percentage is not shown correctly. When fully charged it stays at 100% for a lon time, and at around 50% it shuts down abruptly. When I turn it back on battery is shown at 0%.

So far I tried resetting the SMC again. I tried draining the battery and recharging to 100% two times, but the problem is the same.

Here are the results of my last discharge:

```
11:30 100%
11:53 96%
12:12 83%
12:47 59%
12:59 52%  (shut down)

13:00 0% (plug in - turn on)
```

Battery Information: (fully charged)

```
  Model Information:
  Serial Number:    W0034YMYTE1LA
  Manufacturer: DP
  Device Name:  bq20z451
  Pack Lot Code:    0
  PCB Lot Code: 0
  Firmware Version: 201
  Hardware Revision:    000a
  Cell Revision:    165
  Charge Information:
  Charge Remaining (mAh):   4142
  Fully Charged:    Yes
  Charging: No
  Full Charge Capacity (mAh):   4142
  Health Information:
  Cycle Count:  27
  Condition:    Normal
  Battery Installed:    Yes
  Amperage (mA):    -1917
  Voltage (mV): 11493
```

Battery Information: (20%)

```
Model Information:
  Serial Number:    W0034YMYTE1LA
  Manufacturer: DP
  Device Name:  bq20z451
  Pack Lot Code:    0
  PCB Lot Code: 0
  Firmware Version: 201
  Hardware Revision:    000a
  Cell Revision:    165
  Charge Information:
  Charge Remaining (mAh):   328
  Fully Charged:    No
  Charging: Yes
  Full Charge Capacity (mAh):   1849
  Health Information:
  Cycle Count:  27
  Condition:    Normal
  Battery Installed:    Yes
  Amperage (mA):    1635
  Voltage (mV): 11920
```

Comment: Hello, I noticed that the Full Charge Capacity is reported as 1849 when the battery is empty, and 4142 when fully charged. I think this is the issue. The battery is actually charged to around 2000, but the system thinks it's 4000. So when it's at 50%, spends 2000 charge, it's actually at 0% and shuts down. Do you think it's a battery or SMC problem? Do you know how the computer detects full charge capacity?

Comment: I think you're suffering from "buy cheap, buy twice" & the battery is not up to the same spec as the original. It's likely the Mac thinks it should be 'the original' & doesn't know what to do with one that isn't up to spec.

Comment: I agree, but it was working fine until a week ago. Perhaps the battery died

Comment: How old is it? Is 27 cycles true? if so, send it back [& get a real one].

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by replacing the battery.